# Need a typescript sample with aws-sdk for S3

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to upload an mp3 file to AWS S3 and download it from S3 bucket using typescript.
Anyone have an example or a link for typescript?
The example https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascript/example_code/s3/s3_upload.js I have doesn't compile for typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following project which does the similar kind of requirement as yours

```
function uploadOutputFiles(files: string[], cb4: Callback) {
    parallel(files.map(function (file) {
        return (c) => uploadFile(file, c)
    }), cb4)
}
```

https://github.com/aheld/PodToText